# how to set default value in <p-autocomplete> tag of primeng

Tags: angular, autocomplete, primeng

I want to set default value in  tag, It seems that  tag doesn't have default value property..is there any way to do so..please help me..
. I am using this..its showing suggestions but not able to set default value.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML, try this:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

For Example:

```
<p-autoComplete [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

I fixed the same issue by adding this in html. Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"></p-autoComplete>

in component.ts File

this.text = 'yourValue'
```

Comment: It will set the value in autocomplete , I have checked on my local. Might be error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="cmpId" [suggestions]="filteredCampaignMasterSingle" (completeMethod)="filterCampaignSingle($event)" [size]="30"
                          placeholder="Campaign ID" [minLength]="1" ></p-autoComplete> I have tried this..

Comment: have you bind `cmpId` with your default string ?

Comment: on change event I am creating client-- <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="clientCode1" (change)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)"> in response i am getting cmpId..I printed that cmpId on console..its showing the value of cmpId..but In autocomplete tag its not working

Comment: Yes @pradeep akku is right , In my scenario also this is not working!